# Addsearch ui custom pagination always goes to first page

Tags: javascript, html, npm, pagination, handlebars.js

I am using [addsearch-ui v 0.7.11](https://www.npmjs.com/package/addsearch-search-ui), and I am trying to implement a custom pagination based on [this template example](https://github.com/AddSearch/search-ui/issues/51). However, when I do so, the arrow buttons always go to the first page, regardless of what my current page is. Below is my code:

```
var paginationTemplate = `
  <div class="addsearch-pagination">
    {{#equals currentPage 1}}    
      <button disabled class="addsearch-pagination-disabled-button" aria-label="Previous page">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
          <path d="M4.21214 7.45579L10.0789 1.2253C10.3618 0.9249 10.8206 0.9249 11.1035 1.2253L11.7878 1.95209C12.0704 2.25217 12.0707 2.7382 11.789 3.03892L7.13935 7.99984L11.7887 12.9611C12.0707 13.2618 12.0701 13.7478 11.7875 14.0479L11.1032 14.7747C10.8203 15.0751 10.3615 15.0751 10.0786 14.7747L4.21214 8.54389C3.92929 8.24349 3.92929 7.75619 4.21214 7.45579Z" fill="#10559A"/>
        </svg>
      </button>
    {{/equals}}
    {{#gt currentPage 1}}
      <button data-page="previous" aria-label="Previous page">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
          <path d="M4.21214 7.45579L10.0789 1.2253C10.3618 0.9249 10.8206 0.9249 11.1035 1.2253L11.7878 1.95209C12.0704 2.25217 12.0707 2.7382 11.789 3.03892L7.13935 7.99984L11.7887 12.9611C12.0707 13.2618 12.0701 13.7478 11.7875 14.0479L11.1032 14.7747C10.8203 15.0751 10.3615 15.0751 10.0786 14.7747L4.21214 8.54389C3.92929 8.24349 3.92929 7.75619 4.21214 7.45579Z" fill="#10559A"/>
        </svg>
      </button>
    {{/gt}}
    {{#each pages}}
      <button data-page="{{this}}" aria-label="Go to results page {{this}}" {{#equals ../currentPage this}}data-active="true" aria-current="true"{{/equals}}>
        {{this}}
      </button>
    {{/each}}
    {{#lt currentPage lastPage}}
      <button data-page="next" aria-label="Next page">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
          <path d="M11.7878 8.54407L5.92106 14.7746C5.63811 15.0751 5.17938 15.0751 4.89646 14.7746L4.2122 14.0479C3.92974 13.748 3.9292 13.2618 4.211 12.9611L8.8605 7.99998L4.211 3.03892C3.9292 2.73823 3.92974 2.25205 4.2122 1.95207L4.89646 1.22537C5.17941 0.924876 5.63814 0.924876 5.92106 1.22537L11.7878 7.45593C12.0707 7.75639 12.0707 8.24357 11.7878 8.54407Z" fill="#10559A"/>
        </svg>
      </button>
    {{/lt}}
    {{#equals currentPage lastPage}}    
      <button disabled class="addsearch-pagination-disabled-button" aria-label="Next page">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
          <path d="M11.7878 8.54407L5.92106 14.7746C5.63811 15.0751 5.17938 15.0751 4.89646 14.7746L4.2122 14.0479C3.92974 13.748 3.9292 13.2618 4.211 12.9611L8.8605 7.99998L4.211 3.03892C3.9292 2.73823 3.92974 2.25205 4.2122 1.95207L4.89646 1.22537C5.17941 0.924876 5.63814 0.924876 5.92106 1.22537L11.7878 7.45593C12.0707 7.75639 12.0707 8.24357 11.7878 8.54407Z" fill="#10559A"/>
        </svg>
      </button>
    {{/equals}}
  </div>
`;
```

Please advise.

**Update**:
I also noticed the following query parameter (*it gets added when clicking on the arrow button*) which may be contributing to the issue.

```
&search_page=NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an `svg` inside the `button` seemed to cause issues. When I used CSS for the `svg` file.

HMTL:

```
var paginationTemplate = `
  <div class="addsearch-pagination">
    {{#equals currentPage 1}}    
      <button disabled class="addsearch-pagination-disabled addsearch-pagination-left-button" aria-label="Previous page"></button>
    {{/equals}}
    {{#gt currentPage 1}}
      <button class="addsearch-pagination-left-button" data-page="previous" aria-label="Previous page"></button>
    {{/gt}}
    {{#each pages}}
      <button data-page="{{this}}" aria-label="Go to results page {{this}}" {{#equals ../currentPage this}}data-active="true" aria-current="true"{{/equals}}>
        {{this}}
      </button>
    {{/each}}
    {{#lt currentPage lastPage}}
      <button class="addsearch-pagination-right-button" data-page="next" aria-label="Next page"></button>
    {{/lt}}
    {{#equals currentPage lastPage}}    
      <button disabled class="addsearch-pagination-disabled addsearch-pagination-right-button" aria-label="Next page"></button>
    {{/equals}}
  </div>
`;
```

CSS:

```
.addsearch-pagination-disabled {
    opacity: 0.3;
    background-position: center;
}

.addsearch-pagination-left-button {
    background-image: url('/MyPath/left-chevron.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.addsearch-pagination-right-button {
    background-image: url('/MyPath/right-chevron.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```